# Definition in Kunen

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

In Kunen's second edition of set theory he gives the following definition

Let $(\mathbb{Q},\leq_\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Q})$, and $(\mathbb{P},\leq_\mathbb{P},\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{P})$ be forcing posets and $i:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{P}$. Then i is a complete embedding iff

a) $i(1_\mathbb{Q})=1_\mathbb{P}$.

b) $\forall{q_{1}},{q_{2}}\in{\mathbb{Q}}[q_1\leq{q_2}\rightarrow{i(q_1)\leq{i(q_2)}}]$

c) $\forall{q_{1}},{q_{2}}\in{\mathbb{Q}}[q_1\bot{q_2}\iff{i(q_1)\bot{i(q_2)}}]$

d) If $A$ is a maximal antichain of $\mathbb{Q}$, then $i(\mathbb{Q})$ is a maximal antichain of $\mathbb{P}$.

My question is why is b) not, as intuition would suggest,

b') $\forall{q_{1}},{q_{2}}\in{\mathbb{Q}}[q_1\leq{q_2}\iff{i(q_1)\leq{i(q_2)}}]$?

Is it a typo? You can't really prove b' from b as seen by $\leq_\mathbb{Q}=\{(1,q_{1}), (1,q_{2}), (1,q_{3}), (q_{1},q_{3}), (q_{2},q_{3})\}$ and $\leq_\mathbb{P}=\{(1,p_{1}), (1,p_{2}), (1,p_{3}), (p_{1},p_{2}), (p_{2},p_{3}),  (p_{1},p_{3})\}$ and $i(1)=1$ and $i(q_n)=p_n$.

Comment: The wikipedia article for embedding of posets has an iff for b) though they don't talk about complete embeddings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-embedding so I think this is actually a typo.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the whole point of a complete embedding is to induce a complete embedding of complete Boolean algebras between the completions of the two posets. In forcing the poset can have all sort of properties, but the Boolean completions can have much nicer once instead.

Comment: @Asaf: Ah, OK. I was just curious. Is this the standard definition used in other texts as well? I just found it weird that an embedding would allow for a pathology as the one in in the example I gave. (You get to linearize a square basically which I find weird)

Comment: Here the intuition is that there is a copy of $\mathbb{P}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. That is, $i(\mathbb{P})$ is a copy $\mathbb{P}$ if you delete some of the orderings of element that exists in $\mathbb{Q}$. $i(\mathbb{P})$ is a not a subordering in the sense of substructures in model theory. This is like the difference between a subgraph and the induced subgraph in graph theory. Nevertheless, the point of the complete embedding is to give a nice condition for when two forcings are equivalent.

Comment: As an interesting note, if $\mathbb{Q}$ is separative then the two versions are equivalent.

Comment: @Miha: I think that is the key issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, *(b)* and *(b')* are not equivalent (under the assumption that only *(a)*, *(c)*, and *(d)* hold). Your counterexample is essentially correct. (Note that you used the inverse order!)

However, your main question is answered in Kunen's first edition on the pages 218 and 219 (see *Definition VII.7.1* and *Exercise VII.C2*). Also note that *Lemma III.3.72* in the second edition justifies the differences between the two editions.

Basically, *(b)* and *(b')* are equivalent under the assumption that $ \mathbb{P} $ and $ \mathbb{Q} $ are **separative**. (Maybe you only need that $ \mathbb{Q} $ is separative as *Miha* suggested in the comments.) The proof (of this *Exercise VII.C2*) is a routine computation.